# ExtJS 4 define cache-Control (max-age) with Ext.Loader for required controllers

Tags: caching, extjs, extjs4

I have a ExtJS application where the disabledCache is set to true by default. Now I want to allow caching via

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
    ,disableCaching: false
})
```

Now my application has a hole bunch of controllers, and as far as I understood Ext.Loader downloads these files via the framework. I try to figure out, how to set the headers for the requests which are downloading those files, because I want to define an expiration for those cached files like:

```
proxy:{
    headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'max-age:86400, s-maxage=86400'},
    noCache: false
}
```

Is it possible to define a max-age for the controllers, and if yes, where can I do that.

Or am I horribly wrong with this line of thoughts?

**EDIT:**
After further research I've seen, that Ext.Loader is not supposed to be used in production, but I fear that has already been done. It would still be neat to know how do edit the caching behaviour on Ext.Loader.

Comment: Are you not minifying/optimizing your code via Sencha Cmd or any other tool?

Comment: Not at the moment, no